# Meteor collection empty on client side

Tags: meteor

I am having an issue with a collection.

It is empty only on the client side.  See the following which has been stripped back:

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection("mycollection");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var result = MyCollection.find({name: 'MyName'}, {limit: 25}).fetch();
    console.log(result);
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    var result = MyCollection.find({name: 'MyName'}, {limit: 25}).fetch();
    console.log(result);
}
```

I can see the result correct from the server code but not the client.  What am i missing?

Comment: Are you using autopublish package ? If no, have you published on server (with Meteor.publish) and then subscribed on client "mycollection" ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't removed `autopublish` or you're correctly publishing and subscribing, you're probably running the client code before it has received the data from the server. Try this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Deps.autorun(function() {
    var result = MyCollection.find({name: 'MyName'}, {limit: 25}).fetch();
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

You may get one empty result logged on the client, shortly followed by the correct result (after the client receives the data and reruns the autorun function).

Comment: Instead of Deps I had to use Tracker to resolve a similar issue.

Comment: @alvarez The new name for `Deps` is `Tracker`. They may have removed backwards compatibility since then.